# Сдвинуть символы в строке

Tags: python, строки

Необходимо сдвинуть символы в строке вправо n раз. Например:

```
input:  'qwertyuiopL'
output: 'wertyuiopLq'
```

Мой код:

```
s = 'qwertyuiopL'
n = 10
s = s[-n:] + s[:-n]
print(s)
```

Проблема в том, что, это работает только когда `n > len(s)`

Comment: Попробуйте `n % len(s)`, наоборот, это **не** работает при `n > len(s)`

Answer (score 2):

```
from collections import deque
s = 'qwertyuiopL'
d = deque(s)
d.rotate(-1)
print(''.join(list(d)))
```

> wertyuiopLq

Answer (score 1):

Если я правильно понял задачу то что-то вот такое

```py
n = 10
inp = 'qwertyuiopL'
inp_l = list(inp)
for i in range(n):
    inp_l.insert(len(inp_l), inp_l.pop(0))

print(''.join(inp_l))
```

Answer (score 0):

Как уже писали, проще всего и понятнее всё-таки так, для любого n:

```
s = 'qwertyuiopL'
n = 123
print(s[n % len(s):] + s[:n % len(s)])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
              s = 'qwertyuiopL'
              n = len(s) - 1
              s = s[-n:] + s[:-n]
              print(s)
```